# Java - Iteratively generate powerset in specific order

Tags: java, iteration, powerset

I need to iteratively generate the powerset of a large set, in a specific order. With iteratively I mean that with each call to getNext() (or similar) I get the next element of the powerset in the specific order. Precalculating and storing the entire powerset is not an option as it will be way too large; I am talking of the powerset of a 200-item set. Instead the specific order will allow me to optimize and skip ahead when "uninteresting" powerset elements turn up.

The specified order looks like this, for an ordered five item set with 1 representing to include the item in the powerset element (from left to right, top to bottom):

```
00000 10000 11000 11100 11110 11111
      01000 10100 11010 11101
      00100 10010 11001 11011
      00010 10001 10110 10111
      00001 01100 10101 01111
            01010 10011
            01001 01110
            00110 01101
            00101 01011
            00011 00111
```

With "skip ahead" I mean that if I, for example, determine that 10010 does not fulfill some criterion, I know that none of the following powerset elements with two 1's will fulfill that criterion, so I can skip ahead to examine the powerset elements with three 1's.

I have implemented a partly working solution using shifting of parts of the powerset elements, but have so far not been able to figure out the logic for how to correctly handle all of it. Obviously, the sets with zero 1's and five 1's, and one 1 and four 1's are respective mirror images of each other, the interesting cases are the middle ones above, with two 1's and three 1's. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And where is your 'partly working solution'?

Comment: It is 192 lines long, which is why I did not post it. But... here it is https://chalmersuniversity.box.com/shared/static/u3ivx8bz9panp2zw5pwtt4gcnla6yig5.java

Comment: Have you considered using a standard backtracking recursive search without layering all this abstraction on top?

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about this in the right way, it becomes rather trivial.

```
/***************** PowerSetIterator.java **********************************/
/**
 * @author OppfinnarJocke
 */
/* This class iteratively generates the power set (except for the empty set)
 * First it generates all subsets of num_slots 1, then of num_slots 2, ... 
  * then of num_slots len (of which there is only one)
 */
public class PowerSetIterator
{
    private final int len;
    private final int[] slots;
    private int num_slots;

    public PowerSetIterator(final int len)
    {
        this.len = len;
        this.slots = new int[this.len];
        this.num_slots = 0;
    }

    public int[] next()
    {
        recurse(this.num_slots);

        return this.slots;
    }

    private int recurse(final int right_slot)
    {       
        final int this_slot = right_slot - 1;
        //if(this_slot < 0)
        //  return this.len - this.num_slots;
        assert this_slot >= 0 : "index cannot be < 0";
        // Cannot really grok why this never happens...

        if(!this.isExhausted(this_slot))
            this.slots[this_slot]++;
        else
            this.slots[this_slot] = recurse(this_slot);

        return this.slots[this_slot] + 1;
    }

    /**
     * Skips to next num_slots, and sets up for subsequent iterations
     *
     * @return false if num_slots >= len, that is, if we have already exhausted the powerset generation
     */
    public final boolean nextSize()
    {
        if(this.num_slots >= this.len)
            return false;

        this.num_slots++;
        for(int i = 0; i < this.num_slots; i++)
            this.slots[i] = i;

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the last num_slots elements have all reached their end indexes.
     *
     * @return true if the powerset for this num_slots has been enumerated
     */
    public boolean doneWithThisSize()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < this.num_slots; i++)
            if(isExhausted(i) == false)
                return false;

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * We are finished when len number of slots have been occupied. 
     * 
     * @return true if all sizes and combinations have been exhausted
     */
    public boolean isFinished()
    {
        return this.num_slots == this.len;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether this slot has exhausted its indexes. Slots hold values between 
     * slot_index <= slots[slot_index] <= num_items - num_slots + slot_index
     * 
     * @param slot_index Index of the slot to check
     * @return true if the slot at slot_index is at or beyond its range
     */
    private boolean isExhausted(final int slot_index)
    {
        assert slot_index <= this.slots[slot_index] : "Slot value below slot_index";

        return this.slots[slot_index] >= this.len - this.num_slots + slot_index;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < this.num_slots; i++)
        {
            buf.append(this.slots[i]);
            buf.append(',');
        }

        buf.setLength(buf.length()-1);

        return buf.toString();
    }

    public String toBitString()
    {
        final char[] charray = new char[this.len];
        java.util.Arrays.fill(charray, '0');

        // Fill the correct postions with 1's
        for(int i = 0; i < this.num_slots; i++)
        {
            final int index = this.slots[i];
            charray[index] = '1';
        }

        final String bit_string = new String(charray);
        return bit_string;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int LENGTH = 5;
        PowerSetIterator set_it = new PowerSetIterator(LENGTH);

        while(!set_it.isFinished())
        {
            set_it.nextSize();
            print_it(set_it);

            while(!set_it.doneWithThisSize())
            {
                set_it.next();
                print_it(set_it);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void print_it(final PowerSetIterator set_it)
    {
        System.out.println("set_it.toString() = " + set_it.toString());
        System.out.println("set_it.toBitString() = " + set_it.toBitString());       
    }
}
```